# Generalization Hierarchy and Total Participation

Tags: erd

I was given the following question:

> An entity that is related to another entity through a generalization hierarchy, then... It will always have a total participation with respect to the "father". *T/F and justify*

Well, I think it is true because it must be related to the another entity (that's the meaning of *total participation*).

I do not understand such a question. Can you clear my mind?

Answer (score 0):

In a generalization hierarchy, child entity sets are subsets of their parent entity sets. That means all child entities ARE parent entities, rather than that child entities are related to distinct parent entities as in a containment hierarchy. Subtyping/supertyping isn't a true relationship type in the entity-relationship model.

That said, it's true that every child entity must be identical to a parent entity, and since identity can be viewed as a trivial relationship, it's not wrong to say that child entity sets participate fully in that relationship.